# Xquery Where clause not working when using nested query

Tags: xquery

Good Day,

I'm new to xquery.

I'm trying to execute xquery with a where clause that returns the values greater than a value returned from a nested query as show below. It runs but returns values that are not greater than the returned value

If I use the where clause directly with the value it works fine. I'm using BaseX to execute my query. Appreciate any feedback, I believe the parser may be reading my subquery wrong.

```
for $y in doc("url.xml")/taxi_stations/stand

where $y/taxis>=
(

 for $x in doc("url.xml")/taxi_stations/stand
 where $x/name="Jacksonville"
 return data($x/taxis)
)
return ($y/taxis,$y/name)
```

Comment: Does the inner query return more than one result? An example document would help a lot.

Comment: No the inner query just returns a single value, due to the inner where clause. See answer below. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value of `$taxis`? It's possible your comparisons are happening on strings, not numbers.

In your nested return, you call `data()` on `$x/taxis` - assuming that correctly returns a number value, then `$y/taxis` in your outer `where` clause should probably also be wrapped in `data()`.

However, if there is no schema on your document, then `data()` will simply return a string. In that case you should convert your `taxis` element to a number using `fn:number()` or directly casting it like `$y/taxis/xs:integer(.)`.

Comment: @RiyadSattaur Please read my answer more closely. Are you using a schema? If not, then `data()` will not do what you are assuming. What data type do you expect `taxis` to be? If integer, then you can easily test by checking if `$x/taxis instance of xs:integer" is true. If it's not, then your data is not comparable in the way you assume.

Comment: Hi, Yes I am using a schema. The Element for Taxis is #PCDATA. From what I read this saves as text?  I used the number()  functon and it worked! Thank you!